# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ...

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать, что бы в этой строке не было ошибки?

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO article (title,full,short,time,cat) VALUES ('$title','$full','$short','$time','$rescat["id"]')");
```

Сама ошибка

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ...`

Скорее всего он ругается на `$rescat["id"]`, но как сделать так, чтоб он на неё не ругался? Вроде и в одиночных кавычках прописывал...

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO article (title,full,short,time,cat) VALUES ('$title','$full','$short','$time','{$rescat['id']}')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так сделать.

```
 $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO article (title,full,short,time,cat) VALUES ('$title','$full','$short','$time','".$rescat["id"]."')");
```

Answer (score 1):

или еще проще

```
   $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO article (title,full,short,time,cat) VALUES ('$title','$full','$short','$time','$rescat[id]')");
```

Можно в массивах пропускать кавычки в массивах это не будет ошибкой и прочтет как надо.
Только если в адресе массива участвует переменная то тогда ваши варианты рулят)

Comment: привыкай писать правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Уже давненько заставил себя всегда писать в формате

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO article (title,full,short,time,cat) VALUES ('".$title."','".$full."','".$short."','".$time."','".$rescat['id']."')");
```

чего и вам советую.